# Angular 7 Cdk : getting no instance with CdkPortal

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I'm trying to implement a simple portal example.
My class looks like this :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-action-button',
  template: `
    <ng-template cdkPortal>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </ng-template>
  `
})
export class ActionButtonComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  @ViewChild(CdkPortal)
  private portal: CdkPortal;

  // other code here

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.portal);
  }
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
<ng-container *cdkPortal>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-container>
```

But whatever I do, console.log(this.portal); always prints "undefined".

Any suggestions on how to properly instantiate the 'portal' variable are welcome!

Stackeblitz can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9vwv5x)

Comment: I think its because you are using ng-template, ng-template it self is a fragment means doesn't occupy any elements in dom

Comment: @Justcode, but I've also tried ng-container, same result.